# rails - association params selected, but params "changing" on persist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I really am not sure of how to describe this problem and I've never had an issue like this before. I am trying to set up a "has_many :through" association that handles membership requests to a group. The other actions (destroy, update) seem to be working fine. Whenever I initiate the create action in my controller, the object shows that it is being passed the correct params and the association is created. However, it is creating an association only to the group with the "1" id. I have no idea how to clearly explain this problem or solve it. I'll post my log and code below.

To clarify my question: why is the data "changing" when it persists to the database (on create)?

Cliqs = Groups

Log:

```
Started POST "/cliqs/2/cliq_requests" for ::1 at 2016-03-31 20:35:32 -0500
Processing by CliqRequestsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uaVHFgB7digMywl2a/n2GKMtwi691WA/dw2F2mzdkSCK69C46TZICiSp90xldj3hosFwSOPEi3fSOvOSkIVMjA==", "cliq_id"=>"2"}
Cliq Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `cliqs`.* FROM `cliqs` WHERE (2) LIMIT 1
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
(0.0ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `cliq_requests` (`cliq_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 1, '2016-04-01 01:35:32', '2016-04-01 01:35:32')
(198.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cliqs
Completed 302 Found in 237ms (ActiveRecord: 199.0ms)
```

Controller Action:

```
def create
    @cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])
    @cliq_request = current_user.cliq_requests.new(cliq: @cliq)

    if @cliq_request.save
        redirect_to cliqs_path
    else
        redirect_to current_user
    end 
end
```

Other Actions (just in case):

```
def update
    @cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])
    @cliq_request = CliqRequest.find(params[:id])
    @cliq_request.accept
end

def destroy
    @cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])
    @cliq_request = CliqRequest.find(params[:id])
    @cliq_request.destroy
    if @cliq_request.destroy
        redirect_to cliqs_path
    else
        redirect_to current_user
    end
end
```

And the Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :owned_cliq, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Cliq', dependent: :destroy

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships

has_many :cliq_requests, dependent: :destroy

end

class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user

has_many :cliq_requests, dependent: :destroy                                
has_many :pending_members, through: :cliq_requests, source: :user, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end

class CliqRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
#from
belongs_to :user
#to
belongs_to :cliq

def accept
    cliq.members << cliq.pending_members.find(user_id)
    destroy
end
end
```

Finally my View:

```
<h1><%= @cliq.name %></h1>

<%= link_to 'Request to join Cliq', cliq_cliq_requests_path(@cliq, @cliq_request), :method => :post %>

<% @cliq_members.each do |cliq_member| %>
<ul><%= link_to cliq_member.username, user_path(cliq_member) %></ul>
<% end %>


<h3>Cliq Requests:</h3>

<ul>
<% @cliq.pending_members.each do |pending_member| %>
<%= link_to pending_member.username, user_path(pending_member) %>
<% end %>
<% @cliq.cliq_requests.each do |cliq_request| %>
<%= link_to "Accept", cliq_cliq_request_path(@cliq, cliq_request), :method => :put %>
<%= link_to "Deny", cliq_cliq_request_path(@cliq, cliq_request), :method => :delete %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try using byebug to inspect `@cliq` right after its assignment in the create method. What is its id?

Comment: Strangely I just think I fixed it. Let me know what you think about this: I changed the code for finding the Cliq in the update action to " cliq = Cliq.find_by(id: params[:cliq_id])" instead of " cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])". Why did this work?

Comment: I'll include an answer, one sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out yourself, using `@cliq = Cliq.find_by(id: params[:cliq_id])` works, and `@cliq = Cliq.find_by(params[:cliq_id])` does not. So why is this the case?

The `find_by` method matches on conditions. Using `find_by`, you can match on any attribute. For example, this would also work:

`@cliq = Cliq.find_by(some_attribute: "foo")`

So using `find_by`, you must specify the `id` attribute in order for the query to return the correct record. Your `find_by` query was actually running SQL that looked something like this:

```
SELECT  `cliqs`.* FROM `cliqs` WHERE (2) LIMIT 1
```

That select statement will return the whole table, and the `LIMIT 1` just grabs the first record.

As a bonus, the preferred rails way to assign `@cliq` based on an `params[:cliq_id]` would be using just `find`, which searches for the record using its primary key:

`@cliq = Cliq.find(params[:cliq_id])`

Comment: Oooooh! Ok, I understand. And I just did that for clarity and it seemed to work more clearly as well. Thanks so much for the explanation! An accepted answer and a upvote for you, Glen Coco! You go Glen Coco!